# Bitbucket ssh key seems to "expire" after a few days

Tags: ssh, permissions, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I have never had this issue before was hoping someone could help explain why this is happening, as I can't find anything online about it.

I was just given access to a new bitbucket project and account. When I first add my ssh key to my new account, I am able to clone things down easily everything works normally. For some reason though, after a few hours, I suddenly start getting `Permission denied (public key)` errors, and the only way i've found to solve it is to delete my previous ssh key and create a brand new one!

I am on a mac and I use ssh-keygen to create my key, and i always run ssh-add to add it to the agent. Then I delete the public key from bitbucket and create a new one with the new key's info, and it starts working again but only for a few hours!!

Is this a setting on the bitbucket i've been given access to? It doesn't seem to be as everyone I've spoken to that also has access does not have this issue. This has always been the way i've added ssh keys and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: I also experienced this. Contrary to most Google search linked posts claims, the Bitbucket SSH Keys does expire after 88 days. I checked when the last SSH Key I added in Bitbucket and then when I had re-add the same local Public key then I calculated the days the previously added key lasted and it turned out to be 88 days exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following to re-authenticate, if applicable:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```